# Science Club Members Question (Pairs) Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The science club members are to work in pairs on an experiment.

A) If there are eight members present, in how many ways can the pairs be formed?
B) If Louis and Simone will not work together, how many different pairs can be formed?

For A), I got $\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$, which gives the correct answer.

However, for B), I don't understand why I'm getting the wrong answer. The correct answer is $2430$, but I understand the problem as, if Louis and Simone are not working as a pair, how many different pairs can be formed? And that seems obvious, since it'll just be my answer to A) minus $1$.

Why am I wrong? What am I not understanding?

Thanks

Comment: There is more than one configuration of groups where Simone and Louis are partners. Consider part A where they still like each other and pair them off first. Then, how many ways are there to pair of the 6 remaining club members. This should tell you how many pairings are not valid for part B.

Answer (score 2):

Restrict the situation to only those where Simone and Louis are already paired off. Then of the 6 remaining members they can be paired off as $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$. Then, subtract this from the total combinations you obtained in part A.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your answer for A. I don't even think you did A right... if you have 8 people need to pair up, the number of ways of arranging that is $\frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!4!}$. Then for B, you need to subtract the following from A: $\frac{(8-2)!}{2!2!2!3!}$.

Comment: Order does not matter in pairs.